# What went into an Edo-era Hyakkumonogatari Kaidankai?

Tags: japan, game, folklore, edo-period

I was looking for information on the Edo-era parlour game [hyakkumonogatari kaidankai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyakumonogatari_Kaidankai). I found a lot of academic sources about kaidan themselves (the history, spread, adaption, influence, etc.) But at a certain point I realised there was almost nothing on the actual *game* part for any time or social class, except for the same handful of rules that have persisted to the modern day. I realise some of these answers are probably lost to time, but I would be interested to know... anything on the subject, really! (Unless I'm going about this all wrong, which is always a possibility ^^;)

In general, what I couldn’t find was information on the event as a social engagement - what was expected of the host? Given that it was at least somewhat expected to be an over-night event, how early were invitees expected to arrive, and when were they expected to leave? Was there a party/food before or after? Who got invited? What level of formality would/could they be? Did women of any class/period participate in kaidankai similar to men's? If not (or in addition) - did their have their own variations on kaidankai? Did they share the same kaidan as the men, or was there a gendered repertoire like some European magic tale traditions?

Bonus question: was this ever a practice in Ryukyu/Okinawa? If it is/was, when was it imported?